# How to create stacked and non-stacked combo barchart with R and ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to have pairs of stacked bars next to single bars in a single barplot.

The twelve stacks of bars shown below are in pairs, but I would like to subdivide them again, adding another bar next to each. I would like to leave the axis the same but move the dashed white bar to a 'dodged' position beside the stacked bar.

The data and code listed below were used to create the chart with R (3.0.1) and ggplot2 (0.9.3).There are six treatments for each of the 'directed' and 'undirected' experiments. Each treatment has slightly different conditions (unfortunately). One is 'system' (above in chart) and one is SA / SA-Sw (below in chart).

```
    x <- data.frame(
    ConnectType = c("Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Undirected","Directed","Directed","Directed","Directed","Directed","Directed","Directed","Directed","Directed","Directed","Directed","Directed","Directed","Directed","Directed","Directed","Directed","Directed"),
System = c("Mersey","Mersey","Mersey","Mersey","Mersey","Mersey","St. Marg. Bay","St. Marg. Bay","St. Marg. Bay","St. Marg. Bay","St. Marg. Bay","St. Marg. Bay","Sheet Harbour","Sheet Harbour","Sheet Harbour","Sheet Harbour","Sheet Harbour","Sheet Harbour","Mersey","Mersey","Mersey","Mersey","Mersey","Mersey","St. Marg. Bay","St. Marg. Bay","St. Marg. Bay","St. Marg. Bay","St. Marg. Bay","St. Marg. Bay","Sheet Harbour","Sheet Harbour","Sheet Harbour","Sheet Harbour","Sheet Harbour","Sheet Harbour"),
BarType = factor(c("Dams","Culverts","Both","Dams","Culverts","Both","Dams","Culverts","Both","Dams","Culverts","Both","Dams","Culverts","Both","Dams","Culverts","Both","Dams","Culverts","Both","Dams","Culverts","Both","Dams","Culverts","Both","Dams","Culverts","Both","Dams","Culverts","Both","Dams","Culverts","Both"),
                 c("Dams","Culverts","Both")),
QuanMethod = c("SA","SA","SA","SA-Sw","SA-Sw","SA-Sw","SA","SA","SA","SA-Sw","SA-Sw","SA-Sw","SA","SA","SA","SA-Sw","SA-Sw","SA-Sw","SA","SA","SA","SA-Sw","SA-Sw","SA-Sw","SA","SA","SA","SA-Sw","SA-Sw","SA-Sw","SA","SA","SA","SA-Sw","SA-Sw","SA-Sw"),
ScaledGains = c(64.69,19.65,15.66,75.99,9.28,14.73,61.12,4.43,34.45,52.24,12.17,35.59,69.51,10.49,19.99,66.80,18.46,14.74, 93.39,0.22,6.39,90.20,0.45,9.35,81.08,0.00,18.92,77.09,0.01,22.9,87.14,2.19,10.67,88.28,2.51,9.21)
)

# ggplot2 library must be added through packages    
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(grid)

# set bar colours
barcols<- c("#A9A9A9","#000000","#FFFFFF")
bordcols<- c("#A9A9A9","#000000","#000000")
linetypes1 <- c("solid","solid","dashed")

# ggplot all of it 
ggplot(x, aes(x=QuanMethod, 
          y=ScaledGains,
          fill=BarType, 
          color=BarType, 
          linetype=BarType)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
facet_grid(ConnectType~System) +
scale_linetype_manual(values=linetypes1) +
scale_fill_manual(values = barcols) +
scale_color_manual(values=bordcols) +
xlab("Quantification Method") +
ylab("Percent Connectivity Gains") +
theme(legend.position = "bottom",
      legend.title =element_blank())
```

[image: example chart - either grey or black should be stacked![][1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use the 'group' tag in ggplot().  I simply added a new column to the data that defined the group.  In this case 'dams' and 'culverts' got a 0 and 'dams+culverts' got a 1.  I called the column 'group1'.

```
ggplot(x, aes(x=QuanMethod, 
      y=ScaledGains,
      fill=BarType, 
      color=BarType, 
      linetype=BarType,
      group=group1)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
facet_grid(ConnectType~System) +
scale_linetype_manual(values=linetypes1) +
scale_fill_manual(values = barcols) +
scale_color_manual(values=bordcols) +
xlab("Quantification Method") +
ylab("Percent Connectivity Gains") +
theme(legend.position = "bottom",
legend.title =element_blank())
```